# What is the effect of Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "auto";?

Tags: apt, updates, unattended-upgrades

I wanted to upgrade a production system (through staging, first) to 20.04. Backups and recovery options were in place. All went smoothly as expected. I did `do-release-upgrade -d`, because I didn't want to wait until the first point release (20.04.1).

However, reviewing all the configuration changes (a combination of looking at diffs from `etckeeper` and matching with `debsums -ce`), I noticed `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` now has this line:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "auto";
```

This was previously set to:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "false";
```

And so I was wondering if this in line with my desired configuration. I'd like to be able to use `unattended-upgrades` as before, **but I definitely don't want anything other than LTS releases.**

I looked at the manual pages for `apt.conf`, `apt_preferences`, `apt-config` and `unattended-upgrade`, but could not find a description of that configuration option. [This community help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) also didn't list the option. [This question here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1146193/11316) was the only one referencing this particular option, but doesn't answer my question either.

**Q:** So what does `Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease` do when set to `"auto"` and where can I find more information about the settings and their respective effect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation seems sparse, so I had a look at [the code](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/9761d071186b275c817f300dc3ed70b0cfb8443d/unattended-upgrade#L2054-L2079):

```py
if apt_pkg.config.find("Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease") == "auto":
    # snip
        if ((devel.series == DISTRO_CODENAME
             and devel.release is not None
             and devel.release - date.today() > DEVEL_UNTIL_RELEASE)):
            syslog.syslog((_("Not running on this development "
                             "release before %s") %
                          (devel.release - DEVEL_UNTIL_RELEASE
                           - datetime.timedelta(days=1))))
            logging.warning(_("Not running on this development "
                              "release before %s") %
                            (devel.release - DEVEL_UNTIL_RELEASE
                             - datetime.timedelta(days=1)))
            return UnattendedUpgradesResult(True)

            logging.debug("Running on the development release")
elif "(development branch)" in DISTRO_DESC and not\
        apt_pkg.config.find_b("Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease", True):
    syslog.syslog(_("Not running on the development release."))
    logging.info(_("Not running on the development release."))
    return UnattendedUpgradesResult(True)
```

It's pretty readable. Essentially this option only affects users of the current development release (aka [Ubuntu+1](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/871/158442)) (right now, that's Ubuntu 20.10, "Groovy Gorilla"). And if you're on a development release, this enables unattended upgrades if:

- `DevRelease` is `auto` and you're within a window of the release date (set by [`DEVEL_UNTIL_RELEASE`](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/2.4/unattended-upgrade#L105), seems to be 21 days)
- `DevRelease` is `True`.

If you're not on a development release, which you're not if you're on 20.04 after it was officially released, then this option makes no difference one way or the other.