# "unattended-upgrades --dry-run --debug" says "Running on the development release" on 22.04.1 LTS. Why?

Tags: 22.04

Last week I did a clean install of Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS Minimal. I just finished setting up the machine and configured unattended-upgrades. While doing a dry run using `unattended-upgrades --dry-run --debug` it says `Running on the development release` in the logging. Why does it say 22.04.1 LTS is a development release?

Full output of `sudo apt update` per request of user535733

```
freek@raptor:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for freek:
Hit:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
freek@raptor:~$
```

I noticed it will only say `Running on the development release` when `Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease` is set to `auto` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, [which is the default since 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258424/what-is-the-effect-of-unattended-upgradedevrelease-auto)

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue by running `unattended-upgrades --dry-run --debug`, it doesn't say that in my output. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1425648/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`